# Comparing character in two Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, compareto

I want to check if the characters in each String are the same, and can I build a second String which is given
 from the characters from first String. For example I have Random String ="amksomsamk" and i have to compare it to another "askommmaks".

Firstly I write metod which check length

```
     public boolean areEquals(String s1, String s2){
        if (s1.toCharArray().length == s2.toCharArray().length){
            return true;
        }else
            return false;
```

and now I want to check each character in posible easy way.
I will be grateful for your help

PS.
For given example I want to get true in return because characters in this particular Strings are the same. amksomsamk   a:2 m:3 k:2 s:2 o:1 askommmaks  a:2 m:3 k:2 s:2 o:1 If i use equals it won't be working

Comment: So should your above string return `true` since each letter in your first string is in your second string?

Comment: You could convert to arrays, sort arrays, compare arrays.

Comment: You want to check if there are same characters, not considering the position? For example, you want car and rac to be considered equals?

Comment: This is an interesting question and I don't understand why it is being downvoted. Those who downvoted before the edit (just 21 minutes after posting) might want to reconsider.

Answer (score 3):

Convert each `String` to `char[]`

```
char[] str1 = s1.toCharArray();
char[] str2 = s2.toCharArray();
```

Sort each `char[]`

```
Arrays.sort(str1);
Arrays.sort(str2);
```

Check if equal

```
return Arrays.equals(str1, str2);
```

Comment: Perhaps there are alternative approaches that perform better for very long strings, but I can't imagine any other solution being easier to code or understand than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare it just using below function:

```
public boolean isEqual(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.length() != s2.length())
        return false;

    Map<Character, Integer> charsCountMap = getCharsByCount(s1);


    for (char c : s2.toCharArray()) {
        if (charsCountMap.get(c) == null)
            return false;

        charsCountMap.put(c, charsCountMap.get(c) - 1);
    }

    return charsCountMap.values().stream()
            .allMatch(count -> count == 0);
}

private Map<Character, Integer> getCharsByCount(String s) {
    Map<Character, Integer> charsCountMap = new HashMap<>(s.length());

    for (char c : s.toCharArray())
        charsCountMap.put(c, charsCountMap.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);

    return charsCountMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion with StringBuilder strings gives a terse solution, though it's not easy to understand the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "☆★\u4e16\u754c\u4f60dbbbZZ❸";
    String s2 = "Zb☆b\u754cb★\u4e16d❸\u4f60Z";
    boolean matched = (s1.length() != s2.length()) ? false : compareStrings(new StringBuilder(s1), new StringBuilder(s2));
    System.out.println("Same chars for '" + s1 + "' and '" + s2 + "'? " + matched);
}

private static boolean compareStrings(StringBuilder sb1, StringBuilder sb2) {
    if (sb1.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    int ind = sb2.indexOf((String) sb1.subSequence(0, 1));
    return ind == -1 ? false : compareStrings(sb1.deleteCharAt(0), sb2.deleteCharAt(ind));
}
```

This is the output:

> Same chars for '☆★世界你dbbbZZ❸' and 'Zb☆b界b★世d❸你Z'? true